# Merge Publisher - what does <file action="Copy"> actually do in CruiseControl.Net?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, testcomplete

I inherited a project that runs TestComplete scripts from CruiseControl. 
For each Script there is an  entry in CCnet.Config and each entry ends with the following:

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
   <files>
     <file action="Copy">
        C:\Test\Log\TestCompleteResult\TestWebLog.mht
     </file>
   </files>
  </merge>
 <xmllogger />
 <statistics />
```

Which I assumed copies the TestComplete log to that location. However, if I change the location (i.e. to C:\test\log2\TestWebLog.mht), the file still ends up in  C:\Test\Log\TestCompleteResult. I have tried shutting down CruiseControl, rebooting the system etc. and the file still ends up in the same location.

I have deleted the directory and file, checked the time stamp and looked at the log file. All indicate that it is a new file created by the most recent run of the TestComplete script, but it always gets put in the same location:    C:\Test\Log\TestCompleteResult\TestWebLog.mht.

Is there some place else this path could be defined?

Answer (score 1):

From the [CruiseControl.NET Wiki](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task) :

> Copy: instead of merging the data into the build log, it will copy the specified files into a "build" folder under the artefacts folder for the project

In ccnet.config you can specify an **artifact** directory for each project into which the build results will be placed.

```
<project name="Project">
<artifactDirectory>C:\ProjectDir\artifacts</artifactDirectory>
...
</project>
```

The default merge action is to combine the specified file with the result.xml found in the artifact directory.
The "Copy" merge action copies the specified file into the *artifactdirectory\Build* folder.

The file you specify in the `<file>...</file>` tags is the *source* file that will be copied to the artifact folder.

Answer (score 0):

The [`<merge>`](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task) publisher includes an existing file in the build report. If you want to change the location in which the file is generated, you need to change the task configuration (i.e. in the place where TestComplete gets actually invoked).