# Can't get HtmlReportPlugin to work in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I am trying to use the HTML reports generated by my unit tests to show in the CruiseControl.NET dashboard, but I don't know where I'm scewing it up.

I have my report generated in the "CCNetWorkingDirectory". In my "CCNet.config" file I am using the [File Merge Task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task) to copy the report to my "CCNetArtifactDirectory". This is the step that does not work. I tried it in many different ways. I have:

```
<publishers>
    <merge>
        <files>
            <file>
                Index.html
            </file>
            <file action="Copy">
                rep\Index.html
            </file>
        </files>
    </merge>
    <xmllogger/>
</publishers>
```

What should the paths in my configuration file be? My build breaks with the message:

> "Failing Tasks : MergeFilesTask"

I really don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

In my **ccnet.config** file in the **publishers** node I have to copy the report.html like this:

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>
        <file action="Copy">PathToWorkingDirectory\report.html</file>
    </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger />
  <artifactcleanup cleanUpMethod="KeepLastXBuilds"
                   cleanUpValue="50" />
</publishers>
```

The file will be copied to the artifact directory to a folder named like the Build Label. This has to be done due to security reasons:

> HTML Source Location 
>   This plug-in can display any file that is in the build folder under artifacts folder for the project. It cannot display files from any other location (for security reasons).

To display the HTML report you simply have to add this line to your **dashboard.config**:

```
<htmlReportPlugin description="HRMLReport" actionName="htmlreport" htmlFileName="report.html" />
```

This line has to be placed under the **buildPlugins** node.

```
<buildPlugins>
  <buildReportBuildPlugin>
    <xslFileNames>
      <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
    </xslFileNames>
  </buildReportBuildPlugin>
  <buildLogBuildPlugin disableHighlightingWhenLogExceedsKB="50"/>
  <htmlReportPlugin description="HRMLReport" actionName="htmlreport" htmlFileName="report.html" />
</buildPlugins>
```

After these steps your report should be displayed if you navigate in your dashboard to the build which generates the file. There should be a link called **HTMLReport**.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Version:**

Note all the examples at:

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task

are "*.xml" files.

```
<merge>
  <files>
    <file>Nunit*.xml</file>
    <file>FXCop.xml</file>
    <file>resources\**\*.xml</file>
    <file>E:\CruiseControl\BuildRoot\ProjectX\**\coderesults.xml</file>
    <file>E:\CruiseControl\BuildRoot\Project*\**\Business*.xml</file>
  </files>
</merge>
```

You need to merge .xml, not .htm(l).

**Longer Version:**

The merge task merges ~xml.

Whenever there is a build, there is a "MyBuildResults.xml" file, which I call the "super-xml".

If you have a tool (like NUnit(console).exe for example), that tool will push out a file, "NUnitTestResults.xml".

The CruiseControl.NET merge task will then take "NUnitTestResults.xml" (operative thing, it is XML) and "merge" that into the MyBuildResults.xml (again, XML).

That kind of makes sense. You can merge XML into other XML. How could you take any file and merge it into any file, including an .html file. If you merge HTML, what comes first? Last? Middle?

Now, once your have a final "MyBuildResults.xml", there are .XSL files that will transform that into .html that shows up in the CruiseControl.NET project webpage.

You'll notice a bunch of links (to the left) of the CruiseControl.NET webpage...one of them being "NUnit Test Results". But out of the box, if you click it, nothing displays.

That's because no NUnitTestResults.xml has been "merge up into" the super-build-xml file.

If you find the .xsl files that CruiseControl.NET installs for you (or you installed after the fact), take a look at those, that will show you how that .xsl transforms the XML of the "super-build-xml".

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But i understand the XML merging and i works of course exactly like you said.

Comment: Right.  And you're trying to merge a non-xml file, aka, a html file.  That's the issue.

Comment: Sorry i was interrupted when writing the comment. So my problem is that i dont know how to use the [HTML Report Plugin](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/HtmlReportPlugin). The way i understand the HTMLReportPlugin is that i 
have put the html report in my working directory. But the CruiseControl Dashboard can only display html pages that are located in 
the artifacts location so i need to use the [File Merge Task](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task) 
to copy the File to my arifacts dir. Do you have any experience with the HTMLReportPlugin?

Comment: You can't use the File-Merge task.  You need to COPY your .html file to the needed directory.  Then wire up the HTMLReportPlugin.

Comment: Wait.  I see a discrepancy.  http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/HTML+Report+Plugin    This says you can use the File-Merge task.  it doesn't give an example (of course), it just says "you can use the task"............

Comment: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/File+Merge+Task   That says "I'm deprecated".......so this may be where there is conflicting information.   So I don't have an answer, but just showing the discrepancy.

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056840/merge-publisher-what-does-file-action-copy-actually-do-in-cruisecontrol-ne

Comment: Thanks for your help @granadaCoder. I found the solution and posted it below.